# Cloud backup software similar to version control?

Tags: backup

Is there any backup software that

- Allows you to easily view the entire state of a folder at any time (ala GitHub when browsing through a specific commit -- Time Machine does this wonderfully)
- Lets you see the changelog (not necessarily diffs) of a specific file
- Can back up to remote locations over the internet

Comment: One user or multiple users? something similar to Dropbox?
https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/11

Comment: [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) does that automatically (keeping a history of files). Mounting that e.g. via WebDAV, you could simply copy your files there, and it would take care for the rest. Would that be an acceptable solution? There are also different solutions based on Git. // One more clarification request: What OS should the software run on?

Comment: @izzy gld you mentioned ownCloud, I've setup one recently but couldn't get the windows client to work, i get an error in installation, wondering if you could have any ideas?

Comment: Not directly, as I don't use Windows. But as a hint: For most of the stuff (calendars, contacts, etc) you can use the WebGUI – and for easier access to files, check with [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) (there are Windows solutions for this, and ownCloud supports this).